# Automatically Sort Rows in Excel by Date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to self-teach myself VBA code in Excel, but I've run into a problem.

What I'm wanting Excel to do is to automatically order specific rows according to the date entered in specific cells. For example, dates will be entered into cells E36-E40 only, and as they are entered rows 36-40 (**not including column A**) will automatically sort themselves according to the oldest date first.

I've done a macro recording of this and it has spat out this code:

```
Sub AutoSort()

Range("B36:H40").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "E37:E40"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B36:H40")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

I've tried to make this automatic as shown below, however does not work!

```
Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E36, E37, E38, E39, E40")) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
Else
Sub AutoSort()

Range("B36:H40").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "E37:E40"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B36:H40")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End If
End Sub
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646(v=office.15).aspx) method of `Range` leads to a more concise code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E36:E40")) Is Nothing Then _
        Range("B36:H40").Sort key1:=Range("E36"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, SortMethod:=xlPinYin, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

or, encapsulating the sorting operation into a specific sub:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E36:E40")) Is Nothing Then AutoSort Range("B36:H40"), Range("E36")
End Sub


Sub AutoSort(dataRng As Range, orderCol As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    dataRng.Sort key1:=orderCol, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, SortMethod:=xlPinYin, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried it and it works great. I do have another question though, is it possible to add a function that will auto sort the same rows according to the time entered in F36:F40?

Comment: `Sort()` method of `Range` object lets you sort on up to three keys. If you need more then you must use the `Sort()` method of `Worksheet` object

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN definition of `Me`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e58sbke(v=vs.90).aspx): Provides a way to refer to the specific instance of a class or structure in which the code is currently executing.

I used `Me` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET NAME")` because this code is only relevant to the worksheet that calls the event.  I originally used `ActiveSheet` but if a Macro changed the values from a different worksheet than that worksheet would be active and it would be sorted.

- Turn off `EnableEvents`, whenever changing values on the `ActiveSheet` from the `Worksheet_Change` event.  This will prevent the `Worksheet_Change` event from triggering itself causing an infinite loop and crashing Excel.
- Include an Error Handler that will turn the events back on, if an error is thrown.
- The key range started at row 37
- `.Header = xlYes` should be `.Header = xlNo`

---

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ResumeEvents
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E36:E40")) Is Nothing Then
        With Me
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E36:E40"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange Range("B36:H40")
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With

    End If
ResumeEvents:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thomas, isn't `Range("E36, E37, E38, E39, E40")` equivalent to `Range("E36:E40")` ?

Comment: maybe it's worth while, explaining in your answer, that this code belongs in the `Worksheet_Change` event of "SHEET NAME" worksheet

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks again.  I replaced `ActiveSheet` with `Me`, in case, the values are changed from a Macro with a different `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't encapsulate your Subprocedure `AutoSort()` in your other procedure. Put your `AutoSort()` procedure in module, then call it within worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E36, E37, E38, E39, E40")) Is Nothing Then
   Exit Sub
Else
   AutoSort
End If
End Sub
```

Also, change `.Header = xlYes` to `.Header = xlNo` if Row 36 doesn't contain header.